# Combine two chart with the first series of second chart follow the last series of first chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

I want to combine two chart. same type chart. i want the first series of second chart follow the last series of first chart.

Anyone have an idea? please help me. TQ.

Comment: What do you mean by `follow`?

Comment: Follow mean first series of 2nd chart start after last series of 1st chart.

Comment: I still don't understand that. Just loop over the series from the second chart and add them to the first?